# How to write to Apollo store in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo

What is the best way to store a boolean in the store and then retrieve it?

I have a new client like so:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

I can't tell from [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/) if I am supposed to set the default value in `InMemoryCache` like:

```
cache.writeData({  // Property 'writeData' does not exist on type 'InMemoryCache'
  data: {    
    isLoggedIn: false 
  }
});
```

And then retrieve it with:

```
const IS_LOGGED_IN = gql`
  query IsUserLoggedIn {    
    isLoggedIn @client  
  }
`

const { data } = useQuery(IS_LOGGED_IN)
```

Or should I be using the resolver with queries and mutations like so:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  typeDefs,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      isLoggedIn: (_, _args, _ctx) => {
        return false
      }
    },
    mutation: {
      login: (_, _args, _ctx) => {
        return // ...
      }
    }
  }
});
```

From what I can tell, it's a long the lines of what Apollo does [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/local-state/#adding-virtual-fields-to-server-data) but I thought this is more for adding virtual fields to existing query / mutations which also do a network fetch?

Comment: Have you checked reactive variables ? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/reactive-variables/

Comment: Just came across them earlier. Looks like the way to go. Thanks